# Why am I getting timeout and document missing errors while making parallel calls to Apps Script API?

Tags: multithreading, google-apps-script

I'm writing a Google Sheets add-on that copies some data from one spreadsheet to another and then reformats it. The data sets involved are often large (~100k rows), so to avoid hitting the 6-minute timeout limit I break the data into chunks and then run the data-copying function in parallel on each chunk using google.script.run calls from the client side.

On my sample data set of ~100k rows, the first couple of chunks to complete are copied successfully, and the rest are throwing the error "Service Spreadsheets timed out while accessing document with id [spreadsheet id]."

[image: client-side console logging]

And here's what it looks like in the Apps Script dashboard:

[image: apps script dashboard executions - timeout error]

I'm confused by the timeout errors because:

1. I've successfully run the script on a dataset that contains 5000 rows
2. Apps Script dashboard shows the executions failing before 6 minutes (more like 4-5 minutes)
3. Apps Script dashboard logging shows the failed (timed out) executions logging successfully. Logging happens after the setValues() operation (see code below); the only thing that comes after the logging is the return, so I don't understand how it could log successfully and then time out (I thought Apps Script was synchronous... but maybe I'm wrong?)

I'm also not sure about those "Uncaught" errors, but they seem to be showing up on the dashboard as "Document [spreadsheet id] is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)"

[image: apps script dashboard executions - missing document error]

This is the document I'm copying to, and I've confirmed that it still exists on my Drive and I can open it and see the data that was successfully copied. Can a document go "missing" if too many instances of a script are trying to access it simultaneously?

I've experimented with smaller chunk sizes (1000 and 2000 rows) and get the same types of errors.

Here's what my client-side Javascript looks like:

```
// This function is the success handler that runs after another function (which grabs the total # of rows
// from the sheet to be copied, and then creates the new spreadsheet to be copied into) completes
function dataParamsSuccess(dataParameters) {
      // dataParameters = [busHrs, outputSsUrl, lastRow, maxRows, maxColumns]
      var busHrs = dataParameters[0];
      var outputSsUrl = dataParameters[1];
      var lastRow = dataParameters[2];
      var maxRows = dataParameters[3];
      var maxColumns = dataParameters[4];
      console.log(maxRows);
      console.log(maxColumns);

      // Set chunk size
      var chunkSize = 5000; // number of rows in chunk

      // Determine number of chunks
      var numChunks = Math.ceil(lastRow / chunkSize);
      var lastChunkSize = lastRow % chunkSize;
      if ((numChunks-1) * chunkSize + lastChunkSize == lastRow) {
        console.log("Math checks out");
      } else {
        console.log("oops, check your math");
      }

      // Generate status message
      var statusHtml = numChunks + " chunks to be copied";
      for (i=0; i<numChunks; i++) {
        var chunkNum = i+1;
        var chunkNumStr = chunkNum.toString();
        statusHtml += "<div id=\"chunk" + chunkNumStr + "Status\"></div>";
      }
      document.getElementById("statusMsg").innerHTML = statusHtml;

      var startRow = 1;
      // Call copyData once for each chunk
      for (i=0; i<numChunks; i++) {
        var chunkNum = i+1;
        var chunkNumStr = chunkNum.toString();
        var chunkDivId = "chunk" + chunkNumStr + "Status";

        if (chunkNum==numChunks) { // if this is the last chunk, chunk size is smaller
          chunkSize = lastChunkSize;
        }

        var copyParams = [chunkNum, chunkSize, startRow, outputSsUrl];
        google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(copyChunkSuccess)
          .copyData(copyParams);
        document.getElementById(chunkDivId).innerHTML = "Chunk " + chunkNumStr + " copying in progress";
        startRow += chunkSize;
        console.log("startRow: " + startRow.toString());

      }

      // Haven't gotten to the part where I figure out what to do after all chunks are complete yet
    }
```

And here's the server-side Apps Script function being called:

```
function copyData(copyParams) {

  try {
    // copyParams = [chunkNum, chunkSize, startRow, outputSsUrl]
    var chunkNum = copyParams[0];
    var chunkSize = copyParams[1];
    var startRow = copyParams[2];
    var outputSsUrl = copyParams[3];
    var lastRow = startRow + chunkSize;

    // Get input and output sheets
    var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var outputSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(outputSsUrl);
    var outputSheet = outputSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

    // Copy values
    var values = dataSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, chunkSize, 22).getValues();
    outputSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, chunkSize, 22).setValues(values);

    // Logging
    var dataSpreadsheetId = dataSheet.getParent().getId();
    var outputSpreadsheetId = outputSpreadsheet.getId();
    console.log("Chunk " + chunkNum.toString() + " (rows " + startRow.toString() + " through " + lastRow.toString() + ") copied successfully");
    return [chunkNum, startRow, lastRow, "success"];
  } catch(e) {
    return [chunkNum, startRow, lastRow, e.message]; // Return error to client-side; server-side logging is taking too long
  }
}
```

Comment: I see very similar behaviour when using the google Sheets api (v4). If you do calls sequencially there is no issue at all. When you do multiple requests in parallel certain requests time-out. I added retry logic but once a request hangs, the others are hanging as well (all retry attempts time out). So far I only saw this on read requests (`spreadsheet.get`) not on writes...

Answer (score 2):

How about this answer?

In my experience, even when the Spreadsheet service is used, when the continuous accesses occurs with the asynchronous process, I have experienced such issue. At that time, I used the lock service and `setTimeout`. But I'm not sure whether this method can resolve your issue. So please test the following modification. Here, I would like to propose to use the lock service for Google Apps Script side and `setTimeout` for Javascript side. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

The flow of this workaround is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. 10 workers are sent to Google Apps Script side.
2. After 10 workers were sent, it waits for 5 seconds.
3. At Google Apps Script side, 10 workers are received. And these are processed under the lock service.
4. After 5 seconds, at Javascript side, next 10 workers are sent.

By this cycle, the script is run.

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify `copyData` as follows.

```
function copyData(copyParams) {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  if (lock.tryLock(10000)) {
    try {
      // copyParams = [chunkNum, chunkSize, startRow, outputSsUrl]
      var chunkNum = copyParams[0];
      var chunkSize = copyParams[1];
      var startRow = copyParams[2];
      var outputSsUrl = copyParams[3];
      var lastRow = startRow + chunkSize;

      // Get input and output sheets
      var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
      var outputSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(outputSsUrl);
      var outputSheet = outputSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

      // Copy values
      var values = dataSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, chunkSize, 22).getValues();
      outputSheet.getRange(startRow, 1, chunkSize, 22).setValues(values);

      // Logging
      var dataSpreadsheetId = dataSheet.getParent().getId();
      var outputSpreadsheetId = outputSpreadsheet.getId();
      console.log("Chunk " + chunkNum.toString() + " (rows " + startRow.toString() + " through " + lastRow.toString() + ") copied successfully");
      return [chunkNum, startRow, lastRow, "success"];
    } catch(e) {
      return [chunkNum, startRow, lastRow, e.message]; // Return error to client-side; server-side logging is taking too long
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
  }
}
```

#### HTML & Javascript side:

Please modify `dataParamsSuccess` as follows.

```
// This function is the success handler that runs after another function (which grabs the total # of rows
// from the sheet to be copied, and then creates the new spreadsheet to be copied into) completes

async function dataParamsSuccess(dataParameters) {  // <--- Modified
  const wait = (s) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, s));  // <--- Added

  // dataParameters = [busHrs, outputSsUrl, lastRow, maxRows, maxColumns]
  var busHrs = dataParameters[0];
  var outputSsUrl = dataParameters[1];
  var lastRow = dataParameters[2];
  var maxRows = dataParameters[3];
  var maxColumns = dataParameters[4];
  console.log(maxRows);
  console.log(maxColumns);

  // Set chunk size
  var chunkSize = 5000; // number of rows in chunk

  // Determine number of chunks
  var numChunks = Math.ceil(lastRow / chunkSize);
  var lastChunkSize = lastRow % chunkSize;
  if ((numChunks - 1) * chunkSize + lastChunkSize == lastRow) {
    console.log("Math checks out");
  } else {
    console.log("oops, check your math");
  }

  // Generate status message
  var statusHtml = numChunks + " chunks to be copied";
  for (i = 0; i < numChunks; i++) {
    var chunkNum = i + 1;
    var chunkNumStr = chunkNum.toString();
    statusHtml += "<div id=\"chunk" + chunkNumStr + "Status\"></div>";
  }
  document.getElementById("statusMsg").innerHTML = statusHtml;

  var count = 0;  // <--- Added
  var startRow = 1;
  // Call copyData once for each chunk
  for (i = 0; i < numChunks; i++) {
    count++;  // <--- Added
    var chunkNum = i + 1;
    var chunkNumStr = chunkNum.toString();
    var chunkDivId = "chunk" + chunkNumStr + "Status";

    if (chunkNum == numChunks) { // if this is the last chunk, chunk size is smaller
      chunkSize = lastChunkSize;
    }

    var copyParams = [chunkNum, chunkSize, startRow, outputSsUrl];
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(copyChunkSuccess)
      .copyData(copyParams);

    if (count == 10) {  // <--- Added
      console.log("wait");
      await wait(5000);
      count = 0;
    }

    document.getElementById(chunkDivId).innerHTML = "Chunk " + chunkNumStr + " copying in progress";
    startRow += chunkSize;
    console.log("startRow: " + startRow.toString());

  }

  // Haven't gotten to the part where I figure out what to do after all chunks are complete yet
}
```

#### Note:

- I'm not sure whether `5000` of `await wait(5000)` is suitable for your situation. So please modify this value by testing at your situation. In the current value, `5000` is 5 seconds.

#### Reference:

- [Lock Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/lock)